# Highcharts formatting data labels

Tags: highcharts

I Have edited a graph using highcharts and now i want to show some text on last data label with actual value.

HERE is the jsfiddle edit

http://jsfiddle.net/3h7x9jst/2/

Code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    credits:{
        enabled:false
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min:0,
        max:100,
        title: {
            text: 'Score ( % )'
        },
        labels:{
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    legend:{
        enabled:false
    },
    plotOptions: 
    {
        line: 
        {
            lineWidth:2,
            dataLabels: 
            {
                enabled: true,
                formatter:function() 
                {
                    var pcnt = (this.y);
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt,0) + '%';
                }
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 30, 7.4, 21.5, 6]
    }]
});
 });
```

In this graph last data label is 6%. i want to display abc 6% without changing rest.

What could be possible solution ? Any Help

Comment: are you getting the data programatically? do you know how many values will be plotted?

Comment: yes i am getting data dynamically in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a workaround, it depends on your whole code usage.

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3h7x9jst/3/

Logic:

- You've to get the count of the array & store it in a variable in
- jquery (cnt). Init a pointer variable (pntr) to 0 value Increment the
- pntr always in formatter function Check if the pntr is equals to the
- count of array i.e. last value to be plotted so change the label.

Code:

```
$(function () {
var cnt = 7; // Count of the array should be here
var pntr = 0;
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    credits:{
        enabled:false
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min:0,
        max:100,
        title: {
            text: 'Score ( % )'
        },
        labels:{
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    legend:{
        enabled:false
    },
    plotOptions: 
    {
        line: 
        {
            lineWidth:2,
            dataLabels: 
            {
                enabled: true,
                formatter:function() 
                {
                    pntr++;
                    var pcnt = (this.y);
                    if(pntr == cnt)
                    {
                        return 'Your Text Here' + Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt,0) + '%';
                    }else{
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt,0) + '%';
                    }
                }
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 30, 7.4, 21.5, 6]
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! i also applied the same logic while changing color of last DataPoint. But when i apply on formatter function it gets display none. I checked i was making syntax mistakes. Thank You it worked!